# Refresh rate is 120Hz while my screen is 60Hz

Tags: graphics, xrandr, tearing

I don't understand why I have to different refresh rate on my system:

Here is my *xrandr* output:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1600 x 900, maximum 8192 x 8192
DVI-I-1 connected 1600x900+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
   1600x900       60.0*+
   1280x1024      75.0     60.0  
   1152x864       75.0  
   1024x768       75.1     60.0  
   800x600        75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     60.0  
   720x400        70.1  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And my *glxgears* output:

```
$ glxgears
Running synchronized to the vertical refresh.  The framerate should be
approximately the same as the monitor refresh rate.
601 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.982 FPS
600 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.916 FPS
600 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.916 FPS
600 frames in 5.0 seconds = 119.916 FPS
XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
      after 4999 requests (4999 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

I have an nvidea graphics boards.

Comment: Did you try `xrandr --rate 120` to see if it's supported?

Comment: Rate 120.0 Hz not available for this size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Compiz** interferes with the driver's ability to actually refresh at 120 Hz.

You can spend hours of your time wondering why everything (include `glxgears`) reports a 120 Hz refresh rate, yet the screen isn't actually updating that fast. If you have "Desktop Effects" or anything of that nature enabled, turn it off to compare both `xrandr` and `glxgears` refresh rates.

[Source](http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~zwood/teaching/csc572/final11/rsomers/)